# Issue with not being able to pars LDIF file (invalid format (line 5) entry: "cn=schema")

Tags: ldap, ldif, openam

Trying to add a new attribute to a schema by using this command:

`ldapmodify -f ./add-id-attribute.ldif  -h localhost -p 50389 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w mySecretPassword`

And this LDIF file

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributetypes
attributetypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32474 NAME 'myAttribute'
    USAGE userApplications )
    DESC 'The attribute'
```

But it gives me the following response: `ldapmodify: invalid format (line 5) entry: "cn=schema"`

I already changed the line endings to UNIX but that did not help.
I am using a docker image of `OpenAM 6.5.2` which using `OpenDJ` as the directory server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LDiF is not formatted correctly.

The `DESC` line comes after the closing bracket `)` on the USAGE line and can therefore not be parsed.

You need to move the `)` so the attributeTypes definition becomes fully enclosed by `( )`

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributetypes
attributetypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32474 NAME 'myAttribute'
    USAGE userApplications 
    DESC 'The attribute' )
```